# How to select the value of a certain column based on the value of another column (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to reorganize a dataframe in R, so that the value of a new variable for a specific unit matches the year of that unit. I have the value for each unit for all individual years 2010-2020, but individual units are observed in specific years. I have merged the data such that each unit (regardless of its year) has the values of all years 2010-2020 listed. Each yearly value variable is its own column.

How can I code to make it so that the value in the year column determines which column to draw from? I would like to drop that resulting value in a new column, corresponding with the year for that unit.

For example, Unit 4 is observed in Year 2015, so I will select from column 6 (variable 2015), and deposit that value in the new column. But Unit 5 is observed in Year 2016, so I will select the value from column 7 (variable 2016), and deposit that in the new column.

Apologies for the images, but because I am unfamiliar with the markdown table format, this is what a shortened version of the dataframe roughly looks like:

[image]

This is what I would like to create with the new variable:

[image]

Is there a way to code this and select the column based on the value in the Year column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Unit = c("Unit1" ,"Unit2","Unit3") ,
                  Year = c(2010 , 2011, 2012),
                  Variable2010 = c(4,2,2),
                  Variable2011 = c(5,6,1),
                  Variable2012 = c(1,0,7))
```

then add the required column `New_Variable`

```
df$New_Variable <- sapply(1:nrow(df) ,
                   \(x) if(length(grep(df$Year[x] , colnames(df))) > 0)df[x,grep(df$Year[x] , colnames(df))] else NA)
```

**Output**

```
df

  Unit Year Variable2010 Variable2011 Variable2012 New_Variable
1 Unit1 2010          4          5          1            4
2 Unit2 2011          2          6          0            6
3 Unit3 2012          2          1          7            7
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. This works very well. The only problem is that for observations outside of the observed years, it then fills the value of "New_Variable" with a "list()", an empty list object. When I try to export the dataframe to a CSV file, I cannot do so because it says "unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'". Is there a way to convert all of those "list()"s to NAs? That way, I should be able to export it. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer to get ride of missing variable problem .

Comment: This almost works, but now it gives me the message "invalid 'pattern' argument". Should the "else": be placed somewhere else in the formula, or is something missing?